# Is there a way to update visual-studio-code-bin which is installed from the arch wiki

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code

*visual-studio-code-bin* is installed from the arch wiki. The only way I know how to actually update the software is reinstalling it again from the arch wiki which is tedious and inconvenient.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `actually update the software is reinstalling it again from the arch wiki` ? Install `yay`, and then it's just `yay -S visual-studio-code-bin`

Comment: Created a answer regarding KamilCuk s yay suggestion: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72923967/11473934

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to use VS Code on Arch is to use the open source version on the community repos. Which you can install by doing

```
sudo pacman -S code
```

visual-studio-code-bin is the proprietary binary which can be installed from the Arch User Repository.

If for some reason you want to go for the latter approach, you can either use an AUR helper or manage everything manually.
You can see the Arch Wiki's page on AUR helpers which shows the different options you have: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR_helpers
You can use these helpers to help manage your updates just like you would on pacman.

Here's how you would do things manually: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Arch_User_Repository#Installing_and_upgrading_packages

Just as a warning, AUR helpers are not supported by Arch Linux and the manual approach, though less user friendly is the recommended way by the Arch Wiki to manage your AUR Packages.

Answer (score 2):

Old post with a lot of split information so for anyone who finds this later, you have 2 choices:

1. Install the open source version of visual studio code from the official repos.
2. Install the official Microsoft binary version via the AUR that contains some proprietary code from Microsoft that is not available in the fully open version (e.g. some debugging some languages).

Info on how to do this can be found in [the wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code#Installation).

Comment: Yeah, its been a while. Nowadays I just use VsCodium :D

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you installed vscode. If you did `sudo pacman -S code`, then the solution is to run it again. But if you did `yay -S visual-studio-code-bin`, then you should run THIS command again.

Answer (score 1):

To update with the cloned AUR directory.

First update pacman database:

```
pacman-Sy
```

Then in the AUR directory you can update the AUR to the latest version with:

```
git pull
```

Then update dependencies with:

```
makepkg -s
```

Finally you install it:

```
makepkg -i
==> WARNING: A package has already been built, installing existing package...
==> Installing package visual-studio-code-bin with pacman -U...
loading packages...
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) visual-studio-code-bin-1.73.1-1

Total Installed Size:  324.26 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:       29.66 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
```

Answer (score 0):

First a short version:
Simply run

```
sudo pacman -Sy
sudo pacman -S visual-studio-code-bin
```

The longer explanation:

1. Getting the right version of vscode

First of all, "code" and "visual-studio-code-bin" are two different packages. "code" is an open-source release and "visual-studio-code-bin" is an Microsoft-branded release. One of the major differences is that "code" doesn't support any Microsoft Extensions like C/C++, to my knowledge. This information can be found in the arch wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code#Installation. For more detailed information about the differences I'll refer you to the vscode repository: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Differences-between-the-repository-and-Visual-Studio-Code

By running "sudo pacman -S code" you (unintentionally) uninstall "visual-studio-code-bin" and install "code" because of wired some decency conflict.

So if you want to update/install "visual-studio-code-bin" run:

```
sudo pacman -S visual-studio-code-bin
```

This should fix any Problems with no functioning Microsoft-Extensions

Of course if you want to sick to the open-source version you can use

```
sudo pacman -S code
```

2. Fixing your Problem with not updating to the right version

I have to admit this took me ages. I had two machines, one with an freshly installed version of geruda Linux (an arch based distro) and an six moth old version of geruda Linux. Both had vscode installed. At the time of writing this the current version of vscode is 1.59.0-1. Interestingly the my old machine, witch had vscode version 1.58.0-1 installed didn't know that there was an newer version. The newer machine was aware of the the newer version. An simply running pacman -S visual-studio-code-bin didn't change anything. This hinted my to the problem of an not synchronized package database. And forcefully synchronizing the database with

```
sudo pacman -Sy
```

did the trick for me. For a more detialed information I would redirect you to the man pages: https://archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html or this thread https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=117765. After running this command you only need to install vscode with "sudo pacman -S visual-studio-code-bin" or "sudo pacman -S code" to get the newest version of vscode

Comment: error: target not found: visual-studio-code-bin

Comment: @pabrams According to [link](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code) wiki, visual-studio-code-bin is a AUR repository. Therefore, you should run `yay -S visual-studio-code-bin`

Comment: Oh okay. I guess it was there, when this answer was written.  Thanks, your thing worked @Aviad

Answer (score 0):

As rightly said by @AlexanderHD27 code is open source and vscode is microsoft official version but it is not open source. though code is more like an experimental version of of vscode; however, you can install code directly in archlinux using `sudo pacman -S code`  but for the the vscode you have to clone the repository from github and install in the following way:

```
git clone visual-studio-code-bin
```

then `cd visual-studio-code-bin` and `makepkg -si`
remember if you don't have git installed you can do that using `sudo pacman -S git`. As for the update; code is updated during system full update but vscode is not updated. So, you have to cd into the directory again and do `git pull` the `makepkg -si` again.

Answer (score 0):

As KamilCuk and Aviad mentioned there is no `visual-studio-bin` package, since it is a `aur` package you can use `yay` (AUR helper) to get a updateable version. For more information about `yay` see: https://github.com/Jguer/yay.

### Install yay

```
sudo pacman -S --needed base-devel git
git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/yay.git
cd yay
makepkg -si
cd ..
rm -rf yay
```

### Install visual-studio-code-bin with yay

```
# install
yay -S visual-studio-code-bin
```

Answer (score 0):

If you installed vscode via pamac manager in manjaro, try this:
`pamac update`